# How to prevent memory leak when testing with HiveContext in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, testing, pyspark, hivecontext

I use pyspark to do some data processing and leverage HiveContext for the window function.

In order to test the code, I use TestHiveContext, basically copying the implementation from pyspark source code:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/context.html

```
@classmethod
def _createForTesting(cls, sparkContext):
    """(Internal use only) Create a new HiveContext for testing.

    All test code that touches HiveContext *must* go through this method. Otherwise,
    you may end up launching multiple derby instances and encounter with incredibly
    confusing error messages.
    """
    jsc = sparkContext._jsc.sc()
    jtestHive = sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.test.TestHiveContext(jsc)
    return cls(sparkContext, jtestHive)
```

My tests then inherit the base class which can access the context.

This worked fine for a while. However, I started noticing some intermittent process running out of memory issues as I added more tests. Now I can't run the test suite without a failure.

```
"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"
```

I explicitly stop the spark context after each test is run, but that does not appear to kill the HiveContext. Thus, I believe it keeps creating new HiveContexts everytime a new test is run and doesn't remove the old one which results in the memory leak.

Any suggestions for how to teardown the base class such that it kills the HiveContext?

Comment: I ran into the same thing with my own tests in Java. I'm not sure it has a clean shutdown, so the best I came up with was making it a global test singleton.

Comment: I always hear Singleton = bad design but maybe in this case it is the best solution. It would only be used in the test runner. Do you have some example code? I will accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to use a singleton to hold the Spark/Hive context in all your tests, you can do something like the following.

test_contexts.py:

```py
_test_spark = None
_test_hive = None

def get_test_spark():
    if _test_spark is None:
        # Create spark context for tests.
        # Not really sure what's involved here for Python.
        _test_spark = ...
    return _test_spark

def get_test_hive():
    if _test_hive is None:
        sc = get_test_spark()
        jsc = test_spark._jsc.sc()
        _test_hive = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.test.TestHiveContext(jsc)
    return _test_hive
```

And then you just import these functions in your tests.

my_test.py:

```py
from test_contexts import get_test_spark, get_test_hive

def test_some_spark_thing():
    sc = get_test_spark()
    sqlContext = get_test_hive()
    # etc
```